# Forwarding/delegating 2 arguments in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-std

```
class MyClass
  extend Forwardable
  def_delegators :@broker, :add

  def subscribe_in_broker
    @subscribers.map(&method(:add))
  end
end
```

In this example `@subscribers` is a `Hash` and `@broker.add` takes two arguments: `def broker(k,v)`.

This causes `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2)`

Is there a way to use `Forwardable` or a similar solution without this problem? How can I easily delegate an Array with 2 elements to a method which takes two arguments? What would be the equivalent of writing:

```
  def subscribe_in_broker
    @subscribers.map{|k,v| add(k,v) }
  end
```

but using delegation?

Answer (score 1):

It might seem like the block is receiving 2 arguments, but it is actually receiving only a single argument (a 2-element array). Ruby is interpreting the `|x, y|` as if it was `|(x, y)|`. The parentheses (which can be omitted here) *destructure* the single argument into its two pieces.

When you use a `&` with a method, it *also* only gets only 1 argument, and if you want to destructure it, you have to be explicit by using a set of parentheses around `x` and `y`:

```
def add((x,y))
end
```

To be clear, this is a single-argument method that expects the argument to be an array. For example, you call it like this: `add([1, 2])`

Note: this has *nothing* to do with delegation, just the fact that Ruby assumes you intend to destructure in one place, while not in another.

It is possible to yield more than one argument to a block (or a method turned into a proc with '&'), but that is not what `map` does.

It's not obvious to me why `hash.map { |x,y| add(x, y) }` is not adequate for your purposes. To work around that, you'd need to define your own `map` function that yields 2 arguments instead of 1, and that seems like overkill for this.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer.  Mine was rubbish (and I removed it to avoid confusing myself and others).